# Add different classes to list item parents using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list with different levels of depth:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub item 1</li>
      <li>Sub item 2</li>
      <li>Sub item 3
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Subsub item 1</li>
          <li>Subsub item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following jquery script to add a class to the parents:

```
$("ul li ul").parent().addClass("menuparent");
```

Is there a way to add this class only to the top level parent `li`'s and a different class for all other (deeper) parent `li`'s?

Comment: Do you know an id that might be containing the top level `ul` as a direct descendant?

Comment: There is an error in your HTML, did you know that? The inner most UL is not contained in an LI.

Comment: Whoops, thanks, I've amended.
No there is no top level ID - it is a Wordpress site, and WP does not add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
$("ul li ul").parent().addClass("otherclass");
$("ul li >ul").parent().removeClass("otherclass").addClass("menuparent");
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MdBa5/

Comment: Thanks for this. There was a slight mistake in my markup above (which is now corrected) so this doesn't quite work, but I found something very similar that does:

`$("ul.sub-menu").parent().addClass('parent');` and `$("ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu").parent().addClass('deeperlevels').removeClass('parent');`

Answer (score 0):

You could run a closest check to see if there are any parents that are li.

```
if ($element.closest("li").length === 0) {
  $element.addClass("topLvl");
} else {
  $element.addClass("innerLvl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("ul:first>li").addClass("menuparent")
    .find('li>ul').parent().addClass('otherparent');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3UcdM/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
function markNestedLists(par, level){
    par.addClass("level-" + level);

    par.children("li").children("ul").each(function(){
        markNestedLists($(this), level + 1);
    });     
}
markNestedLists($("ul").first(), 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h9xvY/1/

If you know the ID of the parent of the topmost UL you could use it like so:

```
markNestedLists($("#myParent > ul"), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want the names of the classes to be, I'd use this:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li').addClass(function(){
        return 'depth-' + $(this).parents('ul').length;            
    });        
});​
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/3peCS/

If you want special class names, and not number additions, you'd have to run a switch statement. But the concept is the same. Use a function inside `addClass` to determine the depth (by using `parents()`) and return the appropriate value.

Comment: It occurred to me that you may only want classes on the li's that have children. I've modified the example to include a ternary statement that tests for children ul's: http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/3peCS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, there's some absolute reference like an ID or other searchable attribute that is unique to the top-most `ul`, but you can work around that. Either way, the important thing is the child selector: `>` instead of the implicit descendant selector. It will specify that you only want to find `ul`'s that are exactly so many levels below that top-level element.

When, in your base case, you use:

```
$("ul li ul").parent()
```

you get all `ul`'s that are *any* descendant (children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren...) of *any* `li`'s, that are descendant of *any* `ul`'s. Instead, you'd use:

```
$("ul#topmost > li > ul").parent()
```

which gets you only a `ul` that is the *child* of an `li` that is a *child* of the specific `ul` at the top of the tree.

If you don't have an id or other explicit selector for the top of the tree, the top-level `ul` must itself be a child of either a `div` or `body` or some other block-level element. So, you can clearly and distinctly get the hierarchy you want by just adding that parent of the top-level `ul`:

```
$("body > ul > li > ul").parent()
```

Also: I forgot that you also wanted to be able to select the other parent `li`'s that aren't captured by the selector above. You can do that using the `:not` selector, or JQuery's `.not()` method, like so:

```
$("li>ul:not(body > ul > li > ul)").parent()
```

To combine the two lines into one, you'd first add the `deeperParent` class to all such `li`'s, then filter for the top-level parent, and assign `menuParent` only there:

```
$("li>ul").parent().addClass('deeperParent').filter('body > ul > li').
     removeClass('deeperParent').addClass('menuParent')
```